# Lightbox 2 Navigation Symbols not appearing

Tags: lightbox2

Lightbox shows the enlarged image in a popup, but nothing else.  No title and no navigation and closing symbols, no frame-creating animation behavior. I must use chrome's back arrow to return to the original image.  I tested Lightbox in www.yurowcreates.com/Lville60. (To view, use the tab labeled "May 3rd" then click the picture in the upper left-hand corner.)  I am also using Bootstrap.  Could there be any conflicts? I have followed all installation instructions including providing paths to the navigation symbols and using the proper ordering of my HTML link tags and javascript script tags. (See below)

My HTML markup is as follows:

In the head section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0- 
beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384- 
PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet"   href="Style.css"    type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="lightbox.css" type="text/css">
```

In the body section;

```
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <div class="col">
    <a  href="images/sandyandstu.jpg" data-lightbox="sandyandstu" data-title="Sandy and Stu"><img class="mb-5 mb-sm-0" src="images/sandyandstu.jpg" width="300" height= "200"></a>
    </div>
    ...two other images in the same row go here...
  </div>
```

,,,

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" 
 integrity="sha384- 
 KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" 
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

... (ajax and bootstrap scripts)...

```
  <script src="lightbox.js"></script>     
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that image paths are correct and modify `lightbox.css` accordingly to your file structure

Comment: As far as I can see, @Sunburn, the image paths are correct.  I have decided to remove lightbox from my site and look for a simpler solution.  Thanks for your help.